# spark sql query topN with control flow

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jvm

I have a  dataframe  ,I wanted to do a query to get the data if  it meets the requirements of the rule ,else  reorder the data  and  get the  first one .  But  I  don't  know  how  to do  it .
The  dataFrame is  like this , `newtable`

```
+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+
|_id                       |relatedID     |related|u      |pro                      |
+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|196    |196    |[name,100,yyj196,0.8]    |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|196    |196    |[age,102,21,0.9]         |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|196    |196    |[favorite,102,IT,0.7]    |
|[5c3f2de802353b0d870b05e0]|[196, 2542146]|196    |196    |[name,100,yyj196,0.8]    |
|[5c3f2de802353b0d870b05e0]|[196, 2542146]|196    |196    |[age,102,21,0.9]         |
|[5c3f2de802353b0d870b05e0]|[196, 2542146]|196    |196    |[favorite,102,IT,0.7]    |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[name,100,yyj2447005,0.5]|
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[age,101,21,0.5]         |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[favorite,102,iphone,0.5]|
+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+
```

it was  join  from   two other dataframe

here is the  Schema

```
root
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- relatedID: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- related: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- u: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- pro: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fieldID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sourceID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- weight: double (nullable = true)
```

here  is  the code  in  Scala

```
//join  two  dataframe  & create tempview newtable
dfsU.join(dfsu,dfsU("related") === (dfsu("u")),"inner")
     .createTempView("newtable")

    //test  ,The data displayed above 
    val checkdata =  spark.sql("select * from newtable  where  related = 196 or  related = 2447005 or  u = 196 or  u = 2447005 ")
    checkdata.show(false)
    checkdata.printSchema()
    // group  && set  ranks 
    spark.sql("select * ,Row_Number() OVER (partition by  _id , pro.fieldID  ORDER BY pro.weight desc) ranks FROM newtable")
      .createTempView("tmpview")
    //test  , get the  data  from temview 
    spark.sql("select * from tmpview  where  related = 196 or  related = 2447005 or  u = 196 or  u = 2447005 ").show(false)
```

here  is  the  result  .it look  very strange .  it  isn't order by `pro.weight`

```
+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-----+
|_id                       |relatedID     |related|u      |pro                      |ranks|
+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-----+
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[age,101,21,0.5]         |1    |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[favorite,102,iphone,0.5]|1    |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[name,100,yyj2447005,0.5]|1    |
+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-----+
```

**Q1:**
how to get  the data if it's  `pro.weight`  is  max and  group by  `_id` and `pro.field` .  what is the problem  about my query .
**Q2:**
I also  need  to get data in  special `sourceId`  with  appointed `fieldID`
such  as  get  `[age,101,21,0.5]` not  `[age,102,21,0.9]` , even  its weight  lower than 0.9  in  this group. The reason is  `sourceID == 101` is priority .

```
if(pro.fieldID == age  && pro.sourceID == 101 ){
   //get this  data   when  the  field  is  `age`  and  the `sourceId`  fitted   get  this data 
   //[age,101,21,0.5]
   // other  field  also get the max  weight
   // group  by  pro.fieldID , sorted  by  pro.weight  and  the  top one
   //[name,100,yyj196,0.8]
   //[favorite,102,IT,0.7]

}else {
  //group  by  pro.fieldID , sorted  by  pro.weight  and  the  top one
  //both  field  also get the max  weight
  //[age,101,21,0.9]
  //[name,100,yyj196,0.8]         
  //[favorite,102,IT,0.7]
}
```

how  to  do  it .
Thanks in  advance .

**EDIT**
**More  INFO**

```
 val w = Window.partitionBy(tmp.col("_id"),tmp.col("pro.fieldID")).orderBy(functions.desc("pro.weight"))
    tmp.where("related = 196 or  related = 2447005 or  u = 196 or  u = 2447005 ").withColumn("rn", functions.row_number().over(w)).show(false)
    println("----------------------")
    tmp.withColumn("rn", functions.row_number().over(w)).where("related = 196 or  related = 2447005 or  u = 196 or  u = 2447005 ").show(false)
```

Why  the  result  is  different  ?,  they  use the same  data ,the same  'window  fuction '

data format

```
root
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- relatedID: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- related: integer (nullable = true)

+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+---+
|_id                       |relatedID     |related|u      |pro                      |rn |
+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+---+
|[5c3f2de802353b0d870b05e0]|[196, 2542146]|196    |196    |[age,101,21,0.9]         |1  |
|[5c3f2de802353b0d870b05e0]|[196, 2542146]|196    |196    |[name,100,yyj196,0.8]    |1  |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|196    |196    |[age,101,21,0.9]         |1  |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[age,101,21,0.5]         |2  |
|[5c3f2de802353b0d870b05e0]|[196, 2542146]|196    |196    |[favorite,102,IT,0.7]    |1  |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|196    |196    |[favorite,102,IT,0.7]    |1  |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[favorite,102,iphone,0.5]|2  |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|196    |196    |[name,100,yyj196,0.8]    |1  |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[name,100,yyj2447005,0.5]|2  |
+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+---+

----------------------
19/02/01 18:31:11 WARN BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anon$2: Max iterations (100) reached for batch Operator Optimizations
+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+---+
|_id                       |relatedID     |related|u      |pro                      |rn |
+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+---+
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[age,101,21,0.5]         |1  |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[favorite,102,iphone,0.5]|1  |
|[5c3f2dd302353b0d870a7d2f]|[196, 2447005]|2447005|2447005|[name,100,yyj2447005,0.5]|1  |
+--------------------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+---+
```

Comment: Please rewrite the second question or be more specific. I don't understand it :(

Comment: @Andronicus  I wantted to set  priorities for some special data  such as  `fieldID == age && pro.sourceID == 101`  after grouping .

Comment: What do you mean by priorities?

Comment: @Andronicus  I just wanted  to  replaceOne of  the  result     if   it  fit  my condition.   thanks  for your answer  ,I should look into that.

Comment: No problem, I have edited it with the suggestion to the second question

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:**

There is no guarantee, that selecting rows from ordered view without `order by` results in an ordered table. SQL database has the freedom to choose the most suitable method (from performance point of view).

In general I wouldn't recommend ordering view for two reasons: the first one is the cause of your bug - you need to order thing twice, so there is no point, secondly, ordering filtered table is faster, as there are less rows to sort.

**Q2:**

If I understand correctly, you want to exchange some of your rows/columns. You can look into `withColumn()` or simply `map()` with `if` statement inside to convert the ones that fulfill some condition.

Comment: thanks  for your answer ,I also  don't  know  how  solved  this problem  ,when  the data  became  larger  ,the result  is different